# UICollectionViewCell with custom UICollectionViewLayout to create Parallax Animation On Just one subview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Inspired by this tutorial [Custom UICollectionViewLayout Tutorial With Parallax][1]

[1]: https://www.raywenderlich.com/527-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-tutorial-with-parallax I created my own version of parallax collection view.

I am creating the parallax animation and bounce affect on the header, and footer with this logic:

```
 private func updateSupplementaryViews(_ type: Element, attributes: CustomLayoutAttributes, collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if type == .header,
        settings.isHeaderStretchy {

        var delta: CGFloat = 0.0
        let updatedHeight = min(
            collectionView.frame.height + headerSize.height,
            max(headerSize.height , headerSize.height - contentOffset.y))

        let scaleFactor = updatedHeight / headerSize.height

        if contentOffset.y <= 0{
            delta = (updatedHeight - headerSize.height) / 2

        }else{
            delta = (headerSize.height - updatedHeight - abs(contentOffset.y))
        }

        let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: min(contentOffset.y, headerSize.height) + delta)
        attributes.transform = scale.concatenating(translation)

    }else if type == .footer,
        settings.isFooterStretchy {

        var updatedHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
        if collectionView.contentSize.height - contentOffset.y < UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
            updatedHeight = min(
                collectionView.frame.height + footerSize.height,
                max(footerSize.height, abs(((collectionView.contentSize.height - (footerSize.width + deviationDeviceSize)) - UIScreen.main.bounds.height) - contentOffset.y)))
        }else{
            updatedHeight = min(
                collectionView.frame.height + footerSize.height,
                max(headerSize.height, headerSize.height - contentOffset.y))
        }

        let scaleFactor = updatedHeight / footerSize.height
        let delta = ((updatedHeight - footerSize.height) / 2) - footerSize.height
        let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: min(contentOffset.y, footerSize.height) + delta )
        attributes.transform = scale.concatenating(translation)
    }
}
```

Everything works great beside the annoying fact that all my cell subviews are scaling with this animation and I would like to scale only my background image. This seems simple enough but unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to control what subviews are being manipulated by the transformation.

Comment: would it be possible to download the project somewhere?

Comment: Hello, to give you a better help the ideal is that I downloaded the project. But a suggestion follows: (I do not know your level so I'm sorry if I'm saying something basic to you.) When you do something in a view, all subviews that are hierarchically below / within it are affected. Example, if you change the alpha of a view, the subviews are also affected. So from what you've said, I suspect you're doing something that's affecting the subview, so that it does not happen, put your background image (or what's affecting your subview) hierarchically at the same level as your subviews.

Comment: just use `custom attribute` and override `applyAttribute` method

Answer (score 0):

1. What have you set as customAttributes for Element.footer ?
2. What is the footerSize you are setting ?

You have included some implementations around footer in your project which is not visible for us? Mind to share the whole file ?